# Passing table values in Dojo form to Java servlet

Tags: forms, servlets, html-table, dojo, http-post

I am looking to pass parameter values from my dojo form to a Java servlet. I am able to connect to the servlet but I cannot extract the parameters of my form. I am trying to retrieve the value of my "appid" in my servlet. Please help!

Dojo Form (form.jsp)

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.Form" id="myForm" jsId="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data"
    action="UpdateServlet" method="POST">         
    <table id="newTable">
        <tbody><tr>
               <td>ID:</td><td><span id="appid" title="ID"><%=app.getId()%></span></td>
               </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">
         OK
         </button>

</div>
```

UpdateServlet.java

```
public class UpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        String appId = (String) request.getParameter("appid");
        System.out.println("App id is " + appId);
        //Appid is null, unable to extract value
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of a table won't be submitted automatically when the form is submitted. You need to use some kind of form controls. In your case, I think you can add a hidden input control to do that, like below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="appid" value="<%=app.getId()%>">
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I have figured it out after much research!